Threejs black rendered mesh
I'm using a legacy version of threejs (r150) with a custom loader, generating meshes manually with "position" ,"normal" attributes and groups in case of different materials (MeshPhongMaterial).
In some cases the meshes are rendered in black. If I set the flatShading of the material to false they are rendered with colors, but the display is not smooth.
Here a link to Javascript source code and model Source Code
Why?


I've no indexed faces

My mystake while loading buffer from wasm.
